# C99 static inline function with static local variable

Tags: c, inline, c99, static-members, static-functions

If I write something like this in a C99 header:

```
static inline void f()
{
    static int x = 0;
    // Do something with x
}
```

Is it guaranteed that each module including this header gets a separate instantiation of `f()` and its own instantiation of `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by definition, that's what `static` means. The fact that it's in a header is irrelevant. Conceptually, the C preprocessor creates *one* file to compile per `.c` file as if you had just (re)typed all the text in the header into the `.c` yourself.